# Looking for an indexed container with lookup and insertion/deletion in O(log n) in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers

I am looking for an indexed container in C++ which has the following properties:

- get the element at the k-th position in O(log n)
- insert an element at the k-th position in O(log n)
- delete the element at the k-th position in O(log n)

I was thinking about a workaround using a map which works similar, but I can't figure it out.
There is also a container in Java called [TreeList](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html) which has said properties.

Comment: C++ doesn't have such a container.  You'll need to find a library that offers one or make your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an [order statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). It's a binary search tree that keeps track of the size of each subtree, and that information can be used to perform the operations you need in logarithmic time. The C++ standard library doesn't implement such a data structure, so you need to implement your own or use another library. The [GNU policy-based data structures](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/) extension includes this.